# what does ALT_SMP and ALT_UP does?

Tags: linux, arm

I was just navigating into Linux arm kernel tree, I see usage of ALT_SMP and ALT_UP in assembly files, what exactly they are for?

Answer (score 0):

Refering to
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/asm/assembler.h#L169

`ALT_SMP` should mean only execute in `SMP, Symmetric MultiProcessing` systems.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
#define ALT_SMP(instr...) \
9998: instr
#define ALT_UP(instr...) \
.pushsection ".alt.smp.init", "a" ;\
.long 9998b ;\
9997: instr ;\
.if . - 9997b != 4 ;\
.error "ALT_UP() content must assemble to exactly 4 bytes";\
.endif ;\
.popsection
// skipped
#else
#define ALT_SMP(instr...)
#define ALT_UP(instr...) instr
```

Considering this context `UP` should mean `Uni Processor`.

Also from this [mail](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2012-November/134261.html) on `linux-arm-kernel`:

> > The ALT_{UP,SMP} macros are used to patch instructions at runtime
> >     depending on whether we are running on an SMP platform or not. This is
> >     generally done in out-of-line assembly code, but there is also the need
> >     for this functionality in inline assembly (e.g. spinlocks).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: When arm32 smp-enabled kernel runs on a uniprocessor machine, in some places things must be done differently compared to smp machine. For such places ALT_SMP macro provides smp-specific cpu instruction, while ALT_UP - its uniprocessor alternative.

ALT_SMP and ALT_UP macros only have effect on arm32 when CONFIG_SMP_ON_UP is enabled. Now CONFIG_SMP_ON_UP is enabled by default when CONFIG_SMP is selected, i.e. when we're building smp kernel. Enabled CONFIG_SMP_ON_UP means we want our smp kernel to also be able to run on non-smp (i.e. uniprocessor, UP) machines.

The problem is on UP machines some things have to be done differently by smp-enabled kernel. E.g. UP machine may lack wfe instruction. Or tlb cache entry must be invalidated with a different instruction (see `v7wbi_flush_kern_tlb_range` in [tlb-v7.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/mm/tlb-v7.S)):

```
ALT_SMP(mcr p15, 0, r0, c8, c3, 1)  @ TLB invalidate U MVA (shareable)
ALT_UP(mcr  p15, 0, r0, c8, c7, 1)  @ TLB invalidate U MVA
```

This is what ALT_SMP and ALT_UP macros are for - they provide smp and UP variants of the same code. The proper variant is chosen at kernel boot time by detecting the type of machine and patching the code locations (if necessary).

ALT_SMP and ALT_UP macros come in pairs and wrap exactly one cpu instruction each. ALT_SMP wraps smp variant of instruction - this is the main code path and it goes into usual .text section of kernel's ELF. ALT_UP wraps the alternative UP variant of instruction, which goes into special .alt.smp.init ELF section along with the offset to smp instruction's memory location (from [assembler.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/asm/assembler.h)):

```
#define ALT_SMP(instr...)                     \
9998:   instr
#define ALT_UP(instr...)                      \
        .pushsection ".alt.smp.init", "a"     ;\
        .align  2                             ;\
        .long   9998b - .                     ;\
9997:   instr                                 ;\
        .popsection
```

If CONFIG_SMP_ON_UP was enabled, then very early in the kernel boot __fixup_smp routine (part of [head.S](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/head.S)) detects the type of machine (smp or UP). If machine is smp, nothing is done - remember, smp is the main code path, so all ALT_SMP instructions just stay in place. If machine is UP, then __fixup_smp_on_up is called to do live kernel code patching - replacing SMP_ALT cpu instructions with their ALT_UP alternatives.

As told above, ALT_UP instruction variants and offsets to corresponding ALT_SMP mem locations are stored in .alt.smp.init sections as 8-byte records (4-byte offset + 4-byte instruction). During final kernel linking all those sections from object files are merged into one .init.smpalt section by kernel linker script [vmlinux.lds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S). The start/end mem addresses of .init.smpalt are denoted by __smpalt_begin and __smpalt_end symbols. These symbols are used as array boundaries when iterating over 8-byte records during patching.

When CONFIG_SMP_ON_UP is disabled, no .init.smpalt section is created in the final kernel image by vmlinux.lds, i.e. original .alt.smp.init sections are just discarded. Also no machine type detection / instruction patching code is compiled in. SMP_ALT instructions are used.